# How can I send SMS from Java application

Tags: java, sms, sendmessage

I need to send SMS from java desktop application with my credit from my phone number to another number

Please Help

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use various SMS api to send it for you, or you can use Android device to do it for you by transferring the message to detected application...

also good start is this project:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-sms-api/

Comment: I don't need to use Android to use it , I need to use only desktop application

Comment: you need GSM device or API for do this...